# How to present horizontal data vertically in a datagrid either using backend SQL or in frontend vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a data as follows :

```
No1 Name1 No2 Name2 No3 Name3
232 Sanp  453 Awerk 374 Wash
```

I bring this to data table with following query:

```
select No1,Name1,No2,Name2,No3,Name3 from tbl_info
```

Since I have 50 such columns I don't want to show it horizontally. There will be single record.
Need to display data in data grid in below format vertically for better view:

```
No1   232
Name1 Sanp
No2   453
Name2 Awerk
No3   374
Name3 Wash
```

Comment: *"Since I have 50 such columns I cannot show it horizontally"*. That's a non sequitur. You can display it horizontally if you want to.

Comment: Are you talking about a single record?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Let's consider both scenarios single and multiple records

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I have changed that statement. I just need vertical representation instead of horizontal for good look and feel of the data.

Comment: *"Let's consider both scenarios"*. Let's not. Let's consider your specific issue, which is what? A solution for multiple records will cover all possibilities. A solution for a single record specifically may be simpler.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have now edited my content mentioning single record. Please check

Comment: Use a data reader and a `For` loop. `FieldCount`, `GetName` and `GetValue` would be the methods you want.

Comment: Can Pivot or any SQL function help? @jmcilhinney

Comment: `PIVOT` in SQL Server is generally for turning rows into columns, not columns into rows. I've never used it the way you want and, as far as I'm aware, it's not capable of doing so. I guess you could probably query a schema table somehow to get the column names and join that with the table itself but I'm not sure exactly how that would look or whether such a join would be possible. The SQL would probably end up being so messy as to not be worth it. It would be simpler to use what I've already suggested.